# Is a photon a single wavelength of monochromatic light?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wavelength

I am confused about all these different interpretations of what a photon is?

I am looking for a simple and practical interpretation.

Therefore, I am asking herein if a single photon corresponds to a single period $T$ and wavelength $λ$ of the sinosoidal wave function of a poynting vector of monochromatic light?

[image: light poynting vector]

image credits: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/antenna_theory/antenna_theory_poynting_vector.htm

**Update (1st March 2023):** I was asking here a practical question about how a quantum photon could be represented in the theory of classical electrodynamics thus theory of Electromagnetism. I see now it was wrong on my behalf to tag the question with other topics other than "electromagnetism", since the question has got mostly irrelevant answers and comments using QED, QFT and QM effective models and formalism and trying to describe physically any spatial dimensions to the photon. However, effective models using infinities (i.e. photon is a dimensionless-point particle) are not meant to physically describe a particle itself but only its effects and interactions. These effective theories nowhere claim that they are actually physically describe the actual particle. So all these "physical interpretations" are just formalism artifacts and never meant to be used for describing reality.

I have now remedy my mistake and tagged the question only with the Electromagnetism theory related topics.

Comment: A photon is an elementary excitation of a normal mode of an electromagnetic field. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_source). It might help to think about an electromagnetic field inside a cavity, where it should be clear that normal modes can occur "almost like in string instruments".

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes okay I am aware of. But this is not what I  am asking. In the poynting vector graph above, what part of the graph wave function corresponds to a single photon of monochromatic light?

Comment: Yes what you show is an OK representation for a photon .... there are more advanced models but they are likely not necessary for what you need.  Your picture shows 3 photons ..... but photons don't usually line up this way .... the picture is likely trying to show how the photon is moving in time.

Comment: Most probably you will find that the metaphor you use depends on the application you are trying to make. Interpretations, as such, should be considered as potentially  useful but ultimately disposable.  The equations that work are what you should be working on. As somebody said "shut up and calculate." https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1768652#:~:text=%E2%80%9CShut%20up%20and%20calculate%E2%80%9D%20was,%E2%80%9CShut%20up%20and%20calculate.%E2%80%9D

Comment: @BobaFit Better to shut up and do an experiment.

Comment: This won't totally answer your question, but it may help. [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Comment: *I am asking herein if a single photon corresponds to a single period $T$ and wavelength $\lambda$ of the sinosoidal wave function of a poynting vector of monochromatic light?* If that were the case, photons would be a classical concept.

Comment: John, "shut up and do the experiment" will not help here.  I don't think anyone here disputes the expected outcome of processes involving light.  If you can think of an experiment that would distinguish among the many metaphors/models of a photon, let me know.

Comment: Following up on @Ghoster, (before I get too far, let's make it clear that his answer to your question is "no".)   A picture, mental or physical  that provides a complete-ish metaphor for the nature of light has not  been invented as far as I know, and I think I would know.  The nature of light is completely foreign to our world and the way our brain has evolved to understand it.  So with that in mind, your question is akin to "How fast can a unicorn run?"

Comment: @PhysicsDave *Your picture shows 3 photons.* No, it doesn’t. It shows three wavelengths of a classical electromagnetic wave.

Comment: @garyp And that's the point. Experiments are physics, indistinguishable metaphors aren't.

Comment: How does a question with 3 answers getting 6 up  votes get   3 down votes?

Comment: @JEB In my opinion this is an interesting practical and novel question in PSE  trying to find common ground between QED and classical EM. How you can upvote answers and downvote the question which is answered really escapes me... There is no right or wrong question.

Comment: @JEB It's a perfectly good question. There have been many questions here concerning the nature of light.  I don't get it, either.

Comment: @garyp quantum optics is not simple. I have an intro too it, and takes about 10 pages of dense math to attempt a position space description of the Fock state $|1\rangle$.

Comment: Basically,- yes. An idealized photon is monochromatic plane wave momentum transfer.

Comment: After your update, your questions is asked in your third sentence, and is very clear.  The answer is:  no.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

From an *Electromagnetic Theory* classical standpoint and *energy-wise* description, form my experience, educationally it is **perfectly fine** to equalize a single photon with one wavelength period of a Poynting vector of monochromatic light, during its propagation in space.

Since the energy of a single photon is equal with the energy of a single wavelength of monochromatic light consisting from these photons according to the general expression:

$$E_{Ph}=E_{wl}=hc/λ.$$

where $h$, $c$ and $λ$ are the *Planck constant* , the s*peed of light* in free space and the *wavelength* of light accordingly.

Notice, the Poynting vector illustration shown in the question's figure could represent a beam of monochromatic light with the photoemitter calibrated to output sequentially an ideally one photon each time. Of course if there are more than one photons output each time then they would stack together and increase the intensity of the beam (i.e. amplitude in the poynting vector shown). But yes, the figure shown assumes one photon is transmitted each time in sequence on the poynting vector.

Sine wave function is 100% compatible with the spin 1 thus 2π-symmetry characteristic of a normal photon. Energy-wise, with the assumption that the amplitude shown in the Poynting vector wave illustration herein corresponds to a single photon each time present in the photon train, the illustration is correct. Surely as an isolated particle the photon is not a sine wave rather a standing wave however its interaction with its environment when propagating through space is as an electromagnetic sine wave. The later is exactly what this Poynting vector is showing.

Also, to complete the above Poynting vector **educational**  representation of a single photon of monochromatic light propagating through space with $c$ speed and say of angular  frequency $ω$ in rad/s shown in the question's figure above, we must be able to calculate the Poynting vector amplitude *(i.e. intensity of single photon of monochromatic light of a given frequency).*

"The magnitude of amplitude of the Poynting vector (energy flow) of the photon is:

$$
\mathscr{P}_0=\varepsilon_0 c E_0^2=\hbar \omega^4 / 4 \pi \alpha c^2
$$

Where, $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck Constant and $α$ the Fine Structure Constant" [[1]](https://doi.org/10.4236/oalib.1107179).

Comment: So a single photon is just a short pulse of electromagnetic radiation, the pulse having one wave length?

Comment: And if I irradiate a photodetector the detector would count one photon every $T$ units of time, where $T$ is the period of the wave?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer The Poynting vector illustration shown in the question's figure could represent a beam of monochromatic light with the photoemmiter calibrated to output sequentially an ideally one photon each time. I don't see why this is not feasible?  Of course if there are more than one photons output each time then they would stack together and increase the intensity of the beam (i.e. amplitude in the poynting vector shown). But yes, the figure shown assumes one photon is transmitted each time in sequence on the poynting vector.

Comment: Okay, then I wonder why [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality_and_uncertainty_principles) clearly states "However, experiments confirm that the photon is *not* a short pulse of electromagnetic radiation". I also wonder why you use the (semi-)classical EM framework when Wikipedia claims "Nevertheless, *all* semiclassical theories were refuted definitively in the 1970s and 1980s by photon-correlation experiments".

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Sine wave function is 100% compatible with the spin 1 thus 2π-symmetry  characteristic of a normal photon. Energy-wise, with the assumption that the amplitude shown in the Poynting vector wave  illustration herein corresponds to a single photon each time present in the photon train, the illustration is correct. Surely as an isolated particle the photon is not a sine wave rather a standing wave however its interaction with its environment when propagating through space is as an electromagnetic sine wave. The later is exactly what this Poynting vector is showing.

Comment: It is certainly true that you may make an electromagnetic wave pulse consisting of a single cycle. This is one implementation of ultra-wideband radio. The resulting radiation is far from monochromatic (that's why it's called "ultra-wideband"). This is not a good model of monochromatic radiation.

Comment: @JohnDoty Irrelevant to what the answer given is all about. For educational reasons this effective representation is fine and I am not alone to this since it can be used for useful calculations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLE-Xq0PFb0

Comment: What experiment do you propose to demonstrate that an isolated single cycle of an EM wave behaves as a monochromatic photon?

Comment: The DS experiment. The EM wave is the interaction field of the photon with its environment during its propagation through space,

Answer (score 5):

A photon, as with any quantum system, is described by its wave function. So when you're asking what a photon looks like this is equivalent to asking what the wave function of a photon looks like.

Now what exactly we mean by the wave function of a photon is a little involved (see [EM wave function & photon wavefunction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28616/em-wave-function-photon-wavefunction) for more on this) but for most purposes we can take the photon to be just the EM wave that we get from solving Maxwell's equations. So the wave function of the photon is just an EM wave suitably normalised. Then your diagram could be showing (part of) the wavefunction of a single photon.

To complicate matters further, quantum particles are always delocalised to some extent. That means they are more like a fuzzy cloud that extends over some region of space rather than the little ball as we might naively picture a particle. Typically the particle would be described as a [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet):

[image: Wave packet]

(picture from the Wikipedia link above)

where the width of the wave packet gives the distance over which the particle is delocalised.

Incidentally this is what John Doty means by:

> A single gamma ray photon from technetium-99m represents an electromagnetic wave train of $\approx 10^{24}$ cycles!

i.e. the photons emitted by technetium-99m decay are delocalised over a distance approximately equal to $10^{24}$ times their wavelength.

So your diagram:

[image: EM wave]

would represent a photon wave packet with a size equal to three wavelengths. It's not a question of where in the picture do we find a photon - the whole picture is the photon.

The next question is where are the individual photons in a light wave, and again this is involved because a light wave, or more precisely a coherent state of photons, does not have a precisely defined number of photons in it. However for most purposes we can take the EM wave of the light to be simple the sum of the EM waves for all the photons in it.

Answer (score 3):

If the photon represents monochromatic light, it is not localized until detected, so you cannot relate it to your diagram the way you wish. In real life, there is no perfectly monochromatic radiation. A single cycle is far from monochromatic: it consists of a broad band of frequencies (energies). Longer sinusoidal wave trains have narrower bandwidths, so they are closer to monochromatic.

A single gamma ray photon from technetium-99m represents an electromagnetic wave train of $\approx 10^{24}$ cycles! It only "collapses" to a specific time of photon emission when it interacts irreversibly with a detector or other object.

Comment: You cannot Fourier physically analyse a fixed single frequency sinusoidal wave. It is fundamental. "A single gamma ray photon from technetium-99m represents an electromagnetic wave train of ≈1024 cycles!" I don't know what exactly you are talking about? Any reference? Are you sure this is a physical explanation and not an effective? How a single photon which is fundamental can be described by other constitutes! I am sure "gamma ray photon" is something different than a single gamma photon. Must be a technical term describing a type of experiments.

Comment: @Markoul11 Multiply the half life by the frequency.

Comment: @Markoul11 Not sure what you mean by "Fourier physically analyze". Fourier analysis is math, not physics. The Fourier transform of a sinusoidal wave is a pair of Dirac delta functions.

Comment: John, I think you should clean this up a little.  It's not clear if you are saying that a photon is monochromatic, but if you are saying that, then it conflicts with your statement about technitium.  Also, your response to @Markoul11 is less than satisfying as it refers to the probability of an atomic transition, not to the properties of light.

Comment: $E_{ph}=h/T$ therefore one wavelength of the poynting vector corresponds perfectly to a single photon. End of story from a classical electrodynamics point of view.

Comment: @Markoul11 In classical electrodynamics, as applied to statistical mechanics (where the Planck relation came from), one cycle of a wave train has only a vaguely defined frequency.

Comment: @Markoul11 can you give a reference to a photon in a classical electrodynamics context? I was not aware the concept of the photon even existed in classical EM. Also, if your statement in your last comment is the "end of (the) story", why did you ask the question if you "know" the conclusion...?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer The planck relation to the question came to me during to commets this thread received. I was asking for a simple and practical representation of a photon on the poynting vector. No need for overcomplicated answers.

Comment: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler". A photon is AFAIK a *fundamentally quantum* object. Your representation is both simple and practical, but if it is also **wrong**, what good does that do...

Comment: @Markoul11 There is no "simple and practical representation of a photon on the Poynting vector." Quantum phenomena were a shock to the Poynting vector and related models: they don't fit.

Comment: I believe that all these complicated theories you are talking are formalism artifacts and not physical and caused by the SM view that photon is a dimensionless-point particle as all fundamental particles. Therefore trying to emulate physical dimensions for a dimensionless point it is only logical to formulate crazy maths which produce akward physical explanations. For me if light cocnsists from photons, it is hard to imagine a phodon having a different wavelenght from the monochromatic light it is consisting?

Comment: @Markoul11 Remember, these "crazy maths" are based on experimental results. The phenomena follow their own rules and are under no obligation to conform to your notions of what's crazy or not.

Comment: I don't agree, the photon model is based in the theoretical assumption that it has no physical spatial dimensions thus infinite, which drives the maths "crazy" and to unnatural conclusions  since both physics and maths are mainly sciences involving finite numbers. SM effective formal model for the photon does not claim  that it is  also physically describing a photon only it effects and interactions.  So, SM should not be used for this question herein and is out of topic IMO. Nevertheless, classical EM is more like a physical theory and less an effective one and is more relevant to answer.

Comment: @Markoul11 Is there a hypothesis here? What experiment do you propose to test it?

Answer (score 2):

A quick inverse answer to the question: *Is a photon a single period of a sine wave?*

No.

But: A coherent classical plane wave has a description in terms of Fock state (photon number states). This is in the quantum optics Hamiltonian formulation of light, which is quite different from the relativistic Lagrangian formulation (QED).

It's called the Glauber state (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state). It's a sum over an infinte number of photon states such that is an eigenstate of annihilation operator.

From there: Express a single period of sine in terms of plane waves (basic Fourier transformation), and the plug those into the coherent state, and see what the Fock space state look like.

It will be an exercise in exponentials and $a$, $a^{\dagger}$.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum physics, every item has both wave and particle qualities.  Nothing is exclusively a traditional particle or a traditional wave.  Each item has frequency and wavelength.  Each has energy and momentum.  Each has spin (often measured as angular momentum), although some have spin zero.  A photon actually has spin 1.  You cannot measure everything all at once.  Measuring some quantities will change others.  Some items combine such that the particle qualities usually stand out more.  Some combine such that the wave properties are more visible.  Mass seems to affect this (although the definition of mass is currently under debate).  An EM wave striking a metal surface and knocking electrons off is an example of the particle-like properties of photons standing out.  A different frequency changes the kinetic energy of individual electrons.  Changing the intensity of the light only increases the number of electrons, not their individual energies.  One photon strikes loose one electron.  On the other hand, things such as diffraction, refraction, and interference emphasize the wave properties of photons.  "Wave packet" is a popular term for these wave/particle items.  We know how to measure them and use them, but we don't really know what they are.